# Suppose that a sequence {$a_n$} is eventually periodic. Prove that {$b_n$} is eventually periodic, given that they are in some relation.

Tags: sequences-and-series, periodic-functions

1. To clarify, a sequence {$x_n$} is called eventually periodic if there exist positive integer $r$ and $p$ for which $x_{n+p}=x_n$ for all $n\geq r$.
2. The relation they have is that,

   (i). $b_{n+1}=b_n+a_{n+1}$,
   if $b_n\leq a_{n+1}$

   (ii). $b_{n+1}=b_n-a_{n+1}$,
   if $b_n> a_{n+1}$

Comment: Do you mean "$x_{n+p} = x_n$ for all $n \geq r$"? For the problem itself, consider the first time after $a_n$ has gotten periodic where you change which of (i) and (ii) is used for $b_n$. That would be my initial guess as to when $b_n$ becomes periodic (unless $a_n$ is evenually constantly $0$, in which case you will be stuck using one of them forever).